# Action Controller: Exception caught - turbolinks issue?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, railstutorial.org

I am following Michael Hartl's Rails guide, and when I load localhost:3000 I get the following error messages in the browser:

```
 Sprockets::FileNotFound in Static_pages#home

 Showing /home/jonathan/Desktop/railsTut/sample_app/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb   where line #6 raised:

couldn't find file 'turbolinks'
 (in /home/jonathan/Desktop/railsTut/sample_app/app/assets/javascripts/application.js:16)
```

This is my file from the aformentioned message

```
// This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.js, which will include     all the files
// listed below.
//
// Any JavaScript/Coffee file within this directory, lib/assets/javascripts,      vendor/assets/javascripts,
 // or vendor/assets/javascripts of plugins, if any, can be referenced here using a     relative path.
//
// It's not advisable to add code directly here, but if you do, it'll appear at the    bottom of the
// the compiled file.
//
// WARNING: THE FIRST BLANK LINE MARKS THE END OF WHAT'S TO BE PROCESSED, ANY BLANK LINE     SHOULD
// GO AFTER THE REQUIRES BELOW.
//
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

also, I am not sure if it is related, but here is my Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.13'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '2.1'
gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '3.0.1'
gem 'faker', '1.0.1'
gem 'will_paginate', '3.0.3'
gem 'bootstrap-will_paginate', '0.0.6'
gem 'jquery-rails', '2.0.2'

   group :development, :test do
    gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.5'
 gem 'rspec-rails', '2.11.0'
 # gem 'guard-rspec', '1.2.1'
 # gem 'guard-spork', '1.2.0'
 # gem 'childprocess', '0.3.6'
 # gem 'spork', '0.9.2'
   end

# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '3.2.5'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '3.2.2'
  gem 'uglifier', '1.2.3'
end

group :development do
  gem 'annotate', '2.5.0'
end

group :test do
gem 'capybara', '1.1.2'
gem 'factory_girl_rails', '4.2.1'
gem 'cucumber-rails', '1.2.1', :require => false
gem 'database_cleaner', '0.7.0'
# gem 'launchy', '2.1.0'
# gem 'rb-fsevent', '0.9.1', :require => false
# gem 'growl', '1.0.3'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg', '0.12.2'
end
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Never mind, I just needed to add gem 'turbolinks' to the Gemfile :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As I see, you dont have 'turbolinks' in your gemfile... just add it! :

- Add `gem 'turbolinks'` to your Gemfile.
- Run `bundle install`.
- Add `//= require turbolinks` to your Javascript manifest file (usually
  found at `app/assets/javascripts/application.js`).
- Restart your
  server, and you're now using turbolinks!

Answer (score 3):

As RomanDev said just remove it, unless like me you were trying to get ride of turbolinks.

In which case remove `//= require turbolinks` from your application.js file.

Answer (score 0):

It took me way too long to realize that adding turbolinks to the gemfile would fix this. I'm also going through Hartl's tutorial as a beginner (obviously).